# Vue 3 - Options API vs Composition API - Load external file into component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following file which is an external file with functions (language.js). I also have created a other component which needs to use language.js (it needs to use the languageText funcion inside language.js). I did used it in a Composition API component. But now I want to get it working in a Options API component. Please check the function inside `methods` called `languageSelector`. Inside this function I want to use the global function from `language.js` (`languageText()`)

Any help?

**Options API template (Form.vue)**

```
<script>
import languageText from '@/composables/language';

export default defineComponent({
    name: 'Form',
    props: {
        processingData: Object,
        formData: Object
    },
    emits: ["gateway"],
      components: {
    Icon
  },
  data() {
    return {
      fieldData: this.formData,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    languageSelector(data) {
      const h = languageText(data) **I want to USE the FUNCTION here.**
      console.log(h)
      return languageText(data)
    },
   }
```

**language.js**

```
    import { ref, computed, watch } from 'vue';
    import { useI18n } from "vue-i18n";
    import { useStore } from "vuex";
    
    export default function language() {
    
        const store = useStore();
        const i18n = useI18n();
    
        const language = computed(() => {
            return store.getters.currentUser.language;
        });
    
        function languageText(json) {
         
            const obj = JSON.parse(json)
            return obj[language.value]
    
        }
    
        return {
            languageText
        }
    }
```